# Removing an older version of TLS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tls

A server I have at home is running with the most up to date version of TLS. I was curious if it is okay to remove the older versions of TLS since I am running the most updated version. I'm just using the server to learn, for those that are curious.

Comment: You typically would disable anything before TLS v1.2 in order to harden the server.  This means any client that wanted to use anything other then TLS v1.2 would be unable to communicate.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the response, I'll write this down. If you submit that as an answer, set it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was curious if it is okay to remove the older versions of TLS since
>   I am running the most updated version.

This is actually what you are suppose to do.  You should only accept the cipher from clients you want to support.  If you allow the older ciphers, depending on which ciphers are allowed, you can force a client to use an older vulnerable cipher.